# Modify an expression involving derivatives of functions by changing variables

Tags: sympy

I am attempting to make a YouTube video in which I demonstrate how SymPy can be used to verify the steps in the derivation of a solution to Schrodinger's equation. There is an expression involving derivatives"

```
u=symbols('u')(r)

diff(u,r,2)
```

and a change of variables (a is constant):

```
r=a*x
```

or

```
u.subs(r,a*x)
```

and I want to get back something like:

```
diff(u,x,2)/a**2
```

I understand that I may need something like

```
u=Function('u')(x)
```

or

```
u=Symbol('u', class=Function)
```

But I have already defined u:

```
u=Function('u')(r)
```

I have been unable to get anything to work. If I differentiate u with respect to x, I get zero because (apparently) SymPy sees u as depending on r but not x. I do not understand the Sympy Function class.

This works for built-in functions like cos:

```
diff(cos(a*x),x)
```

returns

```
-a*sin(a*x)
```

I just want the same behavior for my abstract function u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting for the independent variable in a differential equation is something that is difficult or not yet properly supported in sympy. You can do this:

```
In [9]: u = Function('u')

In [10]: r = Symbol('r')

In [11]: u(r)
Out[11]: u(r)

In [12]: u(r).diff(r)
Out[12]: 
d       
──(u(r))
dr      

In [13]: a, x = symbols('a, x')

In [15]: u(r).diff(r).subs(r, a*x)
Out[15]: 
⎛d       ⎞│     
⎜──(u(r))⎟│     
⎝dr      ⎠│r=a⋅x
```

Part of the problem is that sympy doesn't have a way to represent `u'` as the derivative of the single argument function `u` without differentiating with respect to a symbol.

What is needed is something like `dchange` from Maple:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17590

There are complicated ways to make this work in sympy if needed but those are probably not suitable for a youtube video. I suggest to skip over this section in the video :)

```
In [1]: u = Function('u')

In [2]: a, r, x = symbols('a, r, x')

In [3]: expr = u(r).diff(r, 2)

In [4]: expr
Out[4]: 
  2      
 d       
───(u(r))
  2      
dr       

In [5]: expr.subs(u(r).diff(r, 2), 1/a**2 * u(x).diff(x, 2))    # cheating
Out[5]: 
  2      
 d       
───(u(x))
  2      
dx       
─────────
     2   
    a
```

Comment: the #cheating step you gave is of course mathematically sound and fairly transparent. I can use it and won't have to skip over this section. For sure, if Sympy cannot do it automatically we would be in trouble if the change of variables involved something more complex than simply multiplying be a constant.

Comment: By "skip" I just meant to use the cheating step :)

There is an issue for this https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17590. If you could comment there explaining exactly what before/after you want for the transformation that would be useful. Note that there are multiple interpretations for how this could work. For example in a formal sense it has to be a different function like `u(r(x)) = U(x)` but that's not the convention usually used in Physics I think.